# is it possible to run windows 10 mobile on nokia lumia 610

Tags: 8.1, windows-10-mobile, update, nokia-lumia-610

I have a Nokia lumia 610 and it has windows phone 7.8 and I really want to run windows phone 10 or windows phone 8.1?

I tried to download a certificate off this proxy

http://upwp10.chinacloudapp.cn:7777

But it said the webpage is not avalable

Answer (score 1):

**No.** Phones that originally shipped with Windows Phone 7 (any version of it) can not be upgraded to Windows Phone 8 or Windows 10 Mobile.